# Why are here 1 and 2 in this disjoint union

Tags: haskell

I study the usage of Either in haskell,

It's a example in our course, but I don't understand why 1 and 2 instead of each element in each set.

[image: the image of problem]

Thank you

Comment: It means that the `(1, ...)` elements are from the first operand, and the `(2, ...)` from the second operand.

Comment: In an `Either a b`, with `a` and `b` the sets, `(1, ...)` is `Left`, and `(2, ...)` is `Right`. It shows that although the *heart* occurs in both sets, we make a distinction between the left and right, so `Left Heart` is not the same as `Right Heart`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A disjoint union must have some way to keep the elements from the two sets distinct. This is accomplished here by *[tagging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)* each element with a number that represents the set it came from. So, in the disjoint union of `{ a, b }` with `{ a, c, d }`, which you can write as `{(1, a), (1, b), (2, a), (2, c), (2, d)}`, `(1, a)` represents the `a` from the first set and `(2, a)` represents the `a` from the second set.

In Haskell, we use *data constructors* to construct (values of) *sum types* to represent tagged unions, and `Either A B` is the disjoint union of the types `A` and `B`.